# Install Microstrategy 10.4 on a Windows Server 2012 R2 web server feature issues

Tags: asp.net, iis, microstrategy

I am trying to install Microstrategy 10.4 on a Windows Server 2012 and I got the following errors:

MISSING Web Server Feature: Windows Authentication

and

MISSING Web Server Feature:Application Development ASP.net 3.5

I installed ASP.net 3.5 and configure IIS but still got the same error messages.

Thanks for helping,

Answer (score 0):

You need .NET Framework 4.0 and above for Installing MicroStrategy 10.4.
Please refer the following link for system requirements to install the pre-requisites.

https://microstrategyhelp.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/README104/pages/38305888/MicroStrategy+10.4+System+Requirements#MicroStrategy10.4SystemRequirements-IntelligenceServer

[image]